# modifying value of input text box after clicking on a check box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where I read the the text input value and update a counter which is displayed in another div. In some cases I show a check box along with text input field. At the moment when user select the check box the amount which is entered in the text input field is doubled and the result is showing in the counter correctly.

What am I trying to achieve id when the user select the check box the input field should be doubled along with the counter.

The text input in the betslip is added dynamically. So there might be more individual betlsips with check boxes in the view.

Here is my code (HTML view is generated dynamically through JS)

```
BetSlip.prototype.createSingleBetDiv = function(divId, Bet, winPlaceEnabled) {

    document.betSlip.setSingleCount($('[name=singleBet]').length);
    var id = divId.replace('_div','');

    // If such bet already exists
    if (!document.betSlip.singleDivExists(divId) && document.betSlip.getSingleCount() < maxNumberInBetslipRacing) {
        var singleBetPosition = (Bet.position == null) ? '' : Bet.position;

        var raceInfo = Bet.categoryName + ', ' + raceFullName + '&nbsp;' + Bet.name + ',&nbsp;' + Bet.betTypeName + ' (' + Bet.value.toFixed(2) + ')';

        var div = $('<div name="singleBet" class="bet gray2" id="' + divId + '"/>')
            // Appending div with data
            .data('Bet', Bet)

        // Appending error element
        $(div).append($('<p id="' + divId + '_error" style="display:none;"/>')
                .addClass('alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'))

        // Appending info element
        $(div).append($('<p id="' + divId + '_info" style="display:none;"/>')
            .addClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissable'))

        var bgDiv = $('<div id="bgDiv"/>').appendTo(div)

        // Append left part
        var productName = (Bet.productName != null) ? getBrandBetName(Bet.productName) : Bet.betTypeName;
        var leftDiv = $('<div class="left"/>')
            .appendTo(div)
            // Info abt the bet
            .append($('<p class="title"><b>' + singleBetPosition + '&nbsp;' + Bet.horseName + '</b><span style="float:right">' + productName + '</span></p>'))
            .append($('<p class="title">' + raceInfo + '</p>'))
            .append($('<p/>')
                .addClass('supermid')
                // Creating input field
                .append($('<input type="text" id="' + id + '_input"/>')
                    .keypress(function(event) {validateInputs(event, 'decimal')})
                    .keyup(function() {document.betSlip.updateSinglesTotalPrice()})))

        // Creating WIN / PLACE checkbox selection
        if (winPlaceEnabled) {
            $(leftDiv).append($('<p><input name="winPlaceCheckBox" id="' + id + '_checkbox\" type="checkbox"><b>' + winPlace + '</b></p>')
                .click(function() {document.betSlip.updateSinglesTotalPrice()}))
        }

        // Append Done and Reuse btns
        $(leftDiv).append($('<a id="reuseBtn" class="button confirm gray reuse" style="display: none;"/>').html(reuse).click(function() {document.betSlip.reuseBet(divId)}))
        $(leftDiv).append($('<a id="doneBtn" class="button confirm red donebtn" style="display: none"/>').html(done)
            .click(function(){$('#' + divId).find('a.right.orange').click()}))

        // Append right part
        $(div).append($('<a class="right orange"/>')
            .click(function() {
                document.betSlip.removeSingleBetDiv(divId);
            })
            // Closing btn
            .append($('<div class="icon_shut_bet"/>')))

        // Add div to the bet slip map
        document.betSlip.addSingleDiv(divId, div);

        return div;
    }
    else {
        if(this.getSingleCount() < maxNumberInBetslipRacing){
            $("#betSlipError").show();
            $("#betSlipError").html(sameBet);
            return null;
        }
        else{
            $("#betSlipError").show();
            $("#betSlipError").html(maxBet);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the win/place check box I am calling a function which take cares of updating the final price in the counter (Total bet). I would like to update the same in the input text field as well (double up the input value). In case check box is deselected the input amount should be half (both in input field as well  as in the counter).

Function which updated the total bet value

```
BetSlip.prototype.updateSinglesTotalPrice = function() {
    var totalBet = 0;

    $('[name=singleBet]').each(function() {

        var inputValue = $(this).find('input:text').val();
        // Win / Place
        if (document.betSlip.checkWinPlace(this)) totalBet += Number(inputValue * 2);
        // Win or Place
        else totalBet += Number(inputValue);
    });
    $("#betSinglesTotalBet").html(replaceParams(totBetPrice, [totalBet.toFixed(2), document.betSlip.getCurrency()]));
}
```

Comment: @susheel Could you pls explain a bit more?

Comment: `if($("checkboxelement").is(":checked")){ $("inputbox").val("2"); }else{  $("inputbox").val("1"); }`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/susheel61/2CZtV/352/

Comment: @susheel Well, you are trying to set the hard-coded values, whereas in my case when user enters a value in text input and click the check box the amount is doubled in the text input. After deselecting the check box the amount goes back to the previous state. It's not about setting 1 and 2 as explained by you in your fiddle example. That's just an example I have provided in my question. There are no before and after fixed values.

Comment: you should have specified that in your question. be as clear as possible and get solved as soon as possible. check the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/2CZtV/354/